# Facebook posting wrong domain info in posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-ec2

Recently I moved a site over onto an AWS EC2 instance with about 99% issue free results and a seriously nice boost in performance. There has been one issue though when posting any of my site content over to Facebook. It now reads my AWS public domain name assigned to my EC2 instance rather than my .com address.

So instead of seeing www.mysite.com at the base of each post, I now see ec2-55-555-555-555.compute-1.amazonaws.com. When you click through the link it does go back to the www.mysite.com information, however, visually it's not desirable for my Facebook page.

I've been doing some research over the weekend, but so far no results on a resolutions. Has anyone else come across this issue prior?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resided with the $base_url living inside of settings.php. I'd updated it but it'd not gone into effect fully until a few days later.